# Setting a password on Apache - where to put AllowOverride AuthConfig?

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to password-protect a website using Apache. (Beginner alert.) From another question on serverfault, I've found [these instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-apache-password-protect-directory-with-htaccess-file/), which are really helpful.

But I've immediately hit problems at Step 1 - adding `AllowOverride AuthConfig`. My `httpd.conf` file doesn't look anything like the example given, it's only got one line:

```
ExtendedStatus On
```

In the same directory, there's an `apache2.conf` file which has lots more content, but nothing that looks like a DocumentRoot entry.

Finally, my Apache setup is using a bunch of virtual hosts, and in the `sites-available` directory, there's a file for my site that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blah
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/okfn/var/srvc/blah/pyenv/bin/blah.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/blah.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/blah.custom.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Given all of the above, where do I put `AllowOverride AuthConfig`?

Answer (score 3):

The `AllowOverride` Directive is only valid in `<Directory>` Context

So you would be using some configuration like this

```
<Directory /var/www/pages>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig 
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks, but where should I put that? In the virtual host file in sites-available?

Comment: Actually any configuration file loaded by apache would do. But if you want to find it again in 2 years it would be advisable to put it somewhere near the VirtualHost it is used in.